# Faker not defined in python

Tags: python-3.x, faker

Can some one please help me with the error for the following code in python which prompts error "Faker not defined"

```
import csv
import random
#from faker import Faker 
from datetime import datetime
from faker import Faker
fake = faker.Faker()
rand_date = Faker.date_time() 
print(rand_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you defined it wrong.

Give `fake.date_time()` instead of `Faker.date_time()` and it will work.

Also, `fake= Faker` is enough

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
rand_date = fake.date_time() 
print(rand_date)
```